# Command substitution

Tags: command-substitution

I would like to create a script on SUSE Enterprise Linux, it first asks for a string (representing a date) and then search for all files in a certain directory which contains the string in its filename. If there is an empty input, todays date should be used.

I now have this:

```
read -p "Send files from date (MM-DD-YYYY) : " fromdate
if [[ -z ${fromdate// } ]]
then
    echo "Empty input"
    fromdate=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
fi
echo "Input: $fromdate"
cd /path/to/directory
while IFS= read -r -d '' file ; do
echo "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$fromdate*" -print0)
```

When I enter a date, it works fine, for empty input, I get an error:

```
fromdate: command not found
```

The input is still empty, and all files are displayed.
What could be my mistake? Should I use the 'let'-command?

Comment: Why not just use `find` directly?

Comment: I assume that error is coming from line 5?  Can you comment it out and re run and confirm the error goes away?  My guess is you have a space between `fromdate` and `=`.

Comment: I would also suggest trimming the spaces separately. You seem to check for spaces, but use the string including spaces if it was non-empty?

Comment: Did you perhaps edit this script on a Windows box, then copy it over to a Linux or Unix box without converting EOLs?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (but on CentOS 7.1). Did I miss something?

```
read -p "Send files from date (MM-DD-YYYY) : " fromdate
if [[ -z ${fromdate// } ]]
then
    echo "Empty input"
    fromdate=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
fi
echo "Input: $fromdate"

find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -name "*$fromdate*"
```